# grails log4j not working

Tags: grails, log4j

I am using grails and have my lo4j conf as below directed to path `/var/log/eccount/dataSearch.log` and added package(`com.eccount.trending`) I want to log to `info` level,

```
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
    // appender:
    //
    appenders {
        rollingFile name: 'dataSearch', maxFileSize: 1024, file: '/var/log/eccount/dataSearch.log', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss} %C %m%n")
    }

    info  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate',
           'com.eccount.trending'

    warn   'org.mortbay.log'

    root {
      info 'dataSearch'
      //additivity = true
    }
}
```

Now, in my Java class located at `src/java/` I used `org.sl4j.Logger` as defined below

```
org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("dataSearch");
// code flows here
logger.info("elasticSearchsBuilder", elasticSearchsBuilder);
```

But I see nothing at `/var/log/eccount/dataSearch.log` after application runs. It has following access,

```
$ ls -l /var/log/eccount/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 prayag prayag 0 Oct 25 12:59 dataSearch.log
```

*Error level is working for console (but not writing to a file).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing loggers and appenders. You've declared an appender called `dataSearch` in your DSL but you haven't attached it to any loggers, so the messages are all going to the default `stdout` appender. And your code is asking for a *logger* called `dataSearch`, which you haven't configured.

If you want to send just the `com.eccount.trending` messages to this appender but leave everything else at the default stdout, then instead of adding `com.eccount.trending` to the existing `info` line you should add a new line

```
info dataSearch:['com.eccount.trending'], additivity:false
```

If you want *everything* to log to that file instead of stdout then add

```
root {
  error 'dataSearch'
}
```

In both cases you need to change your code to do `getLogger("com.eccount.trending")` instead of `getLogger("dataSearch")`

Note that if you do go with the `root` approach and leave `com.eccount.trending` in the existing `info` line then your current config has a syntax error - you're missing a comma, it should be

```
       'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate',
       'com.eccount.trending'
```

Comment: I added `root{ info 'dataSearch'}` and then changed `getLogger` to `getLogger('com.eccount.trending')`. Didn't work. Again I tried `info dataSearch:['com.eccount.trending'], additivity:false` with `getLogger('com.eccount.trending')`. Didn't work either

Comment: @PrayagUpd I just noticed you're missing a comma in your configuration, does that help?

Comment: I'm going with `root` approach. But adding `,` couldn't help.

Comment: @PrayagUpd delete the `additivity = true`, that won't work (and even if it did it won't change anything as that's the default anyway).  Apart from that everything looks right.

Comment: Tried removing that as well. But no luck.